# Who decides which security protocol to use (server/client) while making web request with webclient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, webrequest

So I have this code,

```
using (var request = new MyWebClient(600000))
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(integration.OriginalUrl);
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                var errorMsg = "Internet is down!!!! OR File can't be processed.Please check URL";
                _logger.Error(wex);
                throw new Exception(errorMsg);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And when I make a call with this, server rejects it because its on SSL3. If I add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Connection works. Here my question is, which side is deciding to use the protocol. Is it server(them) sets it SSL3 although they have disabled it or, my call decides to use SSL3 by default because I did not set it by default?

If it is my call, it means I have to update 3-4 different deployments in general to update everything. In which case, is there a way to set it globally in each project for .NET?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the server. However there is a high degree of SSL-TLS compatibility and that maybe the "issue" that you are hitting . Dig more at question posted at [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/178561/what-are-the-exact-protocol-level-differences-between-ssl-and-tls)